# What did Nemirovski and Yudin actually do in their 1978 article problem complexity and method efficiency in optimization?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, oracles

What did Nemirovski and Yudin actually do in their 1978 book problem complexity and method efficiency in optimization? I'm struggling to find very much on it.

Answer (score 6):

The English translation of the book, *Problem Complexity and Method Efficiency in Optimization*, can be [downloaded](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Enemirovs/Nemirovskii_Yudin_1983.pdf).  The answer below was written before I was able to obtain a copy of the book.

---

I haven't seen the book itself, but a review of the English translation of the book (which was published in 1983) provides some information that is sufficient to tie this in with later work.

For the review, see:

Darzentas, J. Problem Complexity and Method Efficiency in Optimization. J Oper Res Soc 35, 455 (1984). https://doi.org/10.1057/jors.1984.92

Nemirovski and Yudin analyze the iteration complexity of optimization problems, particularly, the minimization of a convex objective function for which an oracle is available that can compute objective function and gradient values.  The difference between the objective function value of the $k$th iterate and the optimal objective, $f(x^{k})-f(x^{*})$, is studied.  A solution is $\epsilon$-approximate if $f(x^{k})-f(x^{*}) \leq \epsilon$.

For example, it can be shown that for a smooth convex objective function, any algorithm that uses only the objective function and gradient can at best attain $\epsilon=O(1/k^2)$, and that gradient descent is non-optimal because it attains only $\epsilon=O(1/k)$.

In a 1983 paper, Yuri Nesterov introduced an accelerated gradient method that improves on gradient descent and achieves the $O(1/k^{2})$ bound- that result apparently hadn't been obtained when the Nemirovski and Yudin book was published in 1978.

A more recent reference that discusses these kinds of results is Yuri Nesterov's *[Lectures on Convex Optimization, 2nd ed.](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783319915777)* Springer, 2018.

Comment: I think there is a confusion between Nemirovski and Nesterov here. Nesterov proposed the accelerated gradient method in 1983 and is the author of the Lectures on Convex Optimization book.

Comment: @Kas Oops- I can only blame COVID fatigue...  I've updated the answer to correct that error and link to a copy of the (English translation) of the book.